# How do i convert python encode decode

Tags: python, decode, encode

Why are the results different?

```
# fabric
subject = run(openssl x509 -subject -noout -in signCert.pem)
subject = subject.split(b"CN = ")[1] # '\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC' <= type string

# FAIL
subject = '\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC'.replace('\\','\\x')
print(subject.encode('latin1').decode()) #\xEC\xA3\xBC\xEC\x8B\x9D\xED\x9A\x8C\xEC\x82\xAC
```

I want to decode like below

```
# Success

a = '\xEC\xA3\xBC\xEC\x8B\x9D\xED\x9A\x8C\xEC\x82\xAC'
print(a.encode('latin1').decode()) # 주식회사
```

How to convert this string?
'\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC' -> b'\xEC\xA3\xBC\xEC\x8B\x9D\xED\x9A\x8C\xEC\x82\xAC'

Comment: Are you missing quotes in the run command?

Comment: "\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC" is hex expression (binary content) of the string data, which is not readable for human but could be understood by machine, you had better write it directly into a `byte` or `bytearray` (with some format), not a `str` in Python. Refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview).

Answer (score 4):

One way to do what you're asking:

```
s = '\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC'

result = eval('b"{}"'.format(s.replace("\\", "\\x")))

print(result)
print(result.decode())
```

Result:

```
b'\xec\xa3\xbc\xec\x8b\x9d\xed\x9a\x8c\xec\x82\xac'
주식회사
```

However, it is likely that there's a better way to achieve this avoiding all the conversion, if you deal differently with the output from the `run()` command.

The reason the code above works is because it evaluates the new string as it would if the expression had been in code - which is what you're trying to do.

Another (safer) approach would be to split the string over backslashes, convert the hexadecimal into numerical values and construct a bytes object from that:

```
result2 = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in s[1:].split('\\'))

print(result2)
print(result2.decode())
```

Same result. This assumes you can be sure `s` starts with a backslash, hence the `[1:]`.

Comment: The first approach seems like it may not be sufficiently safe. If openssl exits abnormally, a quote may show up in the result. I strongly recommend the second approach.

Comment: You're right @MichaelSohnen although dealing with errors from the call would best be done before this conversion - the second example (definitely preferable) still would fail when provided with an error response from the call, just not potentially catastrophically so.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm so glad I was able to solve it.

Comment: one more question

Comment: ```
s = '\EC\A3\BC\EC\8B\9D\ED\9A\8C\EC\82\AC1' # 주식회사1

result2 = bytes(int(x, 16) for x in s[1:].split('\\'))

ValueError: bytes must be in range(0, 256)

```

Comment: Sounds like the string you're splitting has a value that's not a single hexadecimal value. One way to find out what it is would be to put a `try .. except` around the conversion and print the string when a `ValueError` happens; if your string contains multi-byte sequences, it would be good to know how they're represented and the code code be adjusted to convert larger values.

Comment: No problem 유호영 (is that Ho-Young Yoo?) - if the answer is complete, please tick the checkmark next to it, so others can find it as answered as well and people know no further answers are needed.